# Trabajar columna de tipo string con acentos en pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando con un archivo csv y una de sus columnas es de tipo string y tiene acentos. El problema viene a que quiero mostrar una serie de gráficos mediante `seaborn` (librería de gráficos basda en `matplotlib`) y me muestra el siguiente error.

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)

¿Cómo se puede convertir una columna a `utf-8`? Es decir, yo para un string lo que hago es ponerle delante `u` para convertirlo a unicode pero para un dataframe no sé como hacerlo.

A continuación pongo un fragmento de mi csv.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo saber si el csv está mal? Tiene pinta de ser eso, ya que es un xml2 convertido a csv por conversor online

Comment: ¿Puedes subirlo a algún pastebin? Sólo unas pocas filas es suficiente, donde se vean los caracteres no ascii.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7L4pN0yA

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de gráfica intentaste crear? Yo he probado un `seaborn.countplot(data=df, x="nombre")` con los datos del pastebin y me ha funcionado. Claro que eso no prueba nada. Seguramente por el hecho de "copiar y pegar" a través de un navegador el _encoding_ se habrá arreglado. Habría que tener acceso directo a tu fichero. Si estás en linux podrías tratar de ejecutar `file fichero.csv` a ver qué dice. A veces te indica su _encoding_.

Comment: Una barplot de dos elementos `sns.barplot(x="cantidad", y="nombre", data=df_modif, color="b")`,`sns.barplot(x="total", y="nombre", data=df_modif, color="b")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cómo comenté la problemática proviene de los acentos, es decir mi fichero externo `.csv` estaba codificado (cómo bien sugiere @Abulafia) en algún tipo que me genera error, así que la solución ha sido simplemente forzar que mi `csv` tenga codificación `utf-8`.

Esto lo hago con la siguiente línea de código,

```
data = pd.read_csv('datos.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Nota** Esto no es una solución a lo preguntado, sino un informe de cómo he intentado reproducir el error sin conseguirlo. Quizás debería ser un comentario, pero no me cabía. Lo iré editando cuando tenga más información hasta dar con el problema y la solución.

He grabado los siguientes datos (obtenidos del pastebin proporcionado por el usuario) en un fichero llamado `fichero.csv`, guardándolo con codificación utf8.

```
id_paro,nombre,cantidad,total,vos_anto
3316,RM,123,7215530,28.72
3484,RCM,90,5530693,22.01
3736,PDMS,69,5189333,20.66
1079,COF's,40,3500446,13.93
5063,DC-SISI,9,599289,2.39
4991,DL,8,565501,2.25
1533,BMN,6,301585,1.2
4850,OPG COMÚN,2,923105,3.67
1528,A vinj,2,218467,0.87
4744,aCCa-SER,1,81750,0.33
2744,PICMI,0,219181,0.87
```

He probado a cargar estos datos en un dataframe pandas y a pintarlo con seaborn, a ver si podía reproducir el error del usuario. He fracasado (es decir, he tenido éxito):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("fichero.csv")
sns.barplot(x="cantidad", y="nombre", data=df, color="b")
```

[image: Resultado]

Puede verse que, además de no obtener errores, las etiquetas reproducen correctamente las tildes (véase la fila `OPG COMÚN`)

He probado entonces a re-codificar el fichero como latin1, usando Python para hacerlo:

```
with open("fichero.csv", "rb") as f:
  d = f.read()
with open("fichero.csv", "wb") as f:
  f.write(d.decode("utf8").encode("latin1"))
```

Y entonces sí consigo errores, pero no al pintar con Seaborn, sino antes, al tratar de leer el fichero con pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("fichero.csv")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 7: invalid continuation byte
```

Por tanto no he podido reproducir el problema de NEA.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que el error sea por este apostrofe de COF's que ya se "descontrolan" las columnas?